# bat file # in DOScall

Tags: batch-file, parameter-passing

in my firm there is one batch file where is used Doscall and I try to figure out why.
I have for exemple something like in batch file:

```
DOScall parameterAdvance.bat "#..\Message.bat"
```

Why would any one use DOScall and what is purpose of # in parameter?
I try to find out on google with no clear answer and usage of this parameter in file that it call is strange. The best what come to my mind it is that # search in directory folder with similar name.

Comment: There is no `DOScall` command.  There is a `CALL` command which is required when executing a batch file from a batch file if you want control to return to the calling batch file.  Nobody can answer the question about the `#` until we see the code in that batch file that is using that argument.

Comment: I start calling to all old programmers and I find out that there is a DOScall.exe in windows that can be run with parameters, so it is not cal but it start a DOScall.exe witch parameters. That is why this work and # is just take a first line from file as parameter. This was written by some one 20 years ago.

Comment: The only references I can see to `DOScall.exe` are for OS/2 (REXX). What Operating system is this for? and what exactly do you need help with? What is the content of `parameterAdvance.bat`? and `Message.bat`? as both of those may assist us together with the rest of the content of the batch file containing that line. Currently, you haven't really given us much to base our answers on!